# How to set up a Phone 8.1 pivot with an infinite number of pivotitems using caliburn micro?

Tags: caliburn.micro

I am working on a Phone 8.1 Universal app using the excellent framework caliburn micro 2.0. The application is rather simple, it will show statistics fetched from a WCF service and this information will be filtered by year and month. So I figured the best way to do this is to use the same approach as the Phone 8 native calendar app, which uses the pivot for scrolling each month, and when scrolling from december to january, the year is increased by 1.

I have tried several approaches by following tutorials on how to set this up, but I am totally confused. Every single example suggests that I should set the PivotPage as a Conductor, and then every single pivotItem as a screen, and then when activating the conductor, add every single viewmodel(1 for each pivotitem) in an Items list. That sounds reasonable, when there is a finite number of pivotitems and when the mapping between pivotitem and pivotheader is 1:1. But in my case I have ONE pivotItem that is supposed to be reloaded(disposed/created) every time the user changes pivot, and the data is not filtered by the header itself but rather on a DateTime property in my viewmodel that has the currently selected Year and Month which is used to fetch data from the backend. Not exactly what all the caliburn micro pivot tutorials are about.

So, can anyone guide me on how to design this the "caliburn micro way"...? I have tried something by adding a pivot.itemtemplate and then refresh this by hooking up to the selectionchanged event on the pivot, but this has some rather nasty sideeffects, like when I change the pivot, the previous pivot is not disposed of correctly, causing the visual tree for the app to increase by 30% for each pivot change. I have no idea why it is like that, but it tells me that I should do this 100% caliburn micro instead.

I have a very simple example that I can share if anyone wants to have a go at this, depending on how simple the solution is?

Please help!

/Henrik